# In my virtualenv, I need to use sudo for all commands

Tags: python, sudo, virtualenv

I set up a `virtualenv`, which is working, but for some reason I need to use `sudo` for commands as simple as `mkdir`. Obviously I did something incorrectly. Any idea what it might be?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use sudo to create the virtualenv?

Comment: Please edit the question to describe exactly how you created the virtualenv (which commands and as what user).

Comment: @David, looks like I must have used `sudo` to create it. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check the directory permissions and owner and give:

```
$ sudo chown -R me:me virtualenvdir
$ sudo chmod -R a+rX virtualenvdir
```

change `me` with your username, typically $USER, and `virtualenvdir` with your virtualenv's work directory.

Comment: Thanks.....I figured that out from ~unutbu's answer....I'm gonna switch you to the correct answer though since I think this was a better solution than recreating

Comment: Remember kids, whenever you have to use sudo to do something, it's a permissions problem!

Answer (score 4):

The commands

```
cd test
sudo virtualenv python
```

creates a directory called `python` which is owned by root.

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root      4096 2010-04-17 11:40 python
```

That would force you to use `sudo` for simple things like making a directory inside the `python` directory.

The fix would be to delete the `python` directory (saving data first if necessary) and issue the command

```
virtualenv python
```

without the `sudo`.

Comment: I changed the ownership of those files instead of recreating. I had tried that before but I didn't know about the `-R` flag for `chown`.

Thanks for your help