# pip permission error in virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I try to install bottle inside `virtualenv`:

```
 pip install bottle
```

I get this error:

> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/myapp/env/build'

It seems like permission error, when I create the folder is in root, how can I sudo pip in virtualenv?

Comment: Seems like you've created virtualenv with 'sudo'. You can always use sudo while working with virtualenv (like 'sudo pip install bottle'), change the ownership of the virtualenv folder via chown or recreate virtualenv without sudo. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658902/in-my-virtualenv-i-need-to-use-sudo-for-all-commands.

Comment: Just to be clear, did you install `virtualenv` with sudo?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue.

Just change the owner of the virtualenv directory

```
sudo chown username:username your_directory_name
```